# Segmentation Fault on WSDL request on PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, wso2, wsh

I've created this simple example based on wsdl mode sample of wso2 framework for php.

```
    <?php

try {

    $client = new WSClient(array("wsdl"=>"http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/info.wso?wsdl",
                                 ));

    $proxy = $client->getProxy();   

    $result = $proxy->TopGoalScorers(array('iTopN'=>1));

    echo "TEST!!!<br />";

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';

} catch (Exception $e) {

        echo "Message = ".$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

If I execute this script in a web browser i got a http 324 error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
And when i execute it in a shell it seems to work but at the end i get a segmentation fault error.

The same error will be reproduced using the sample file wsdl_11_client.php

If this line

```
$result = $proxy->TopGoalScorers(array('iTopN'=>1));
```

is commented no segmentation fault error will appear.

I'm using wsf wso2 framework for php version 2.1.0
libxml version 2.7.8
libxslt version 1.1.26
PHP Version 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6
Ubuntu 11.10.

In my php.ini i've added

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/usr/lib/php5/20090626/wsf_c/scripts"

[wsf]
wsf.home="/usr/lib/php5/20090626/wsf_c"
;log_level2 shows warnings and errors
;wsf.log_level=2 
;wsf.log_path="/var/log/wsf"
```

and i've added this extension in /etc/php5/conf.d/wsf.ini

```
; configuration for php WSF module
extension=wsf.so
```

Is my server misconfigurated? Or there are some errors in my php script?
Thanks in advance.
Francesco.

Answer (score 0):

Same for me.

Taking into account the absence of activity on "WSO2 WSF for PHP" project, I suppose it would be better not to use it on production.

The best workaround probably would be to write Java proxy service which communicates with original service and returns something like JSON to PHP.